# Uncaught TypeError: comboSistemas.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-axios, mui

Tengo este componente  de MUI, que alimento a través de una API. Para este requiero un objeto con llaves diferentes que se encuentran en el axios. Sin embargo, muestra los objetos y llaves en la consola pero no los renderiza y envía el error *Uncaught TypeError: comboSistemas.map is not a function*

```html
import axios from 'axios';
import {AxiosComboSistemas } from '../_Axios/AxiosFomr';


const { useState, useEffect } = require("react");

GenericComboAPI.propTypes = {
    endPointURL: PropTypes.string,
    nameAUX: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    valorFiltro: PropTypes.any,
    onChangeFunc: PropTypes.any,
    useChange: PropTypes.bool,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    valorDefault: PropTypes.any,
};

export default function GenericComboAPI({ endPointURL, nameAUX, label, placeholder, valorFiltro, useChange = false, onChangeFunc, disabled, valorDefault }) {

    useEffect(() => {
        AxiosComboSistemas(endPointURL, valorFiltro, setComboSistemas)
        setValor(valorDefault)
    }, [endPointURL, valorFiltro, valorDefault]);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        onChangeFunc(event.target.value)
        setValor(event.target.value)
    }

    const [valor, setValor] = useState(valorDefault);
    const [comboSistemas, setComboSistemas] = useState([]);
    
    return (

        <RHFSelect
            native
            name={nameAUX}
            disabled={disabled}
            label={label}
            placeholder={placeholder}
        >
             {comboSistemas.map((item) => (
  <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
    {item.name} {item.roleName} {item.franchiseName}
  </option>
))}
        </RHFSelect>
    )
}
```

Y aquí está el axios para el combo, las llaves son roles y franchise, ambos son arrays. La consola me permite ver la respuesta 2 veces una para el array de roles y otra para el array de franchise, que defini aquí como rols y franc, respectivamente

```html
export function AxiosComboSistemas(endPointURL, valorFiltro, succesFunc) {
    const urlAUX = HOST_API_SISTEMAS + endPointURL;
    const AUT = `Bearer ####`;
    axios({ method: 'get', url: urlAUX, params: { filtro: valorFiltro }, headers: { 'Authorization': AUT } })
        .then(response => {
            const dataResponse = {
                rols: response.data.roles,
                franc: response.data.franchise
            };
            succesFunc(dataResponse); console.log('Chavos, sí está llamando combo sistemas', dataResponse);

        .catch(error => { console.log('Error en el combo sistemas ', error) })
```

¿Alguien podría orientarme?

Comment: Gracias por responde! Ya lo he intentado, pero aún continua el error, así que hice una función de comboSistemas, ya no marca el error pero no renderiza el selec

Comment: El import del useState y useEffect deberías hacerlo con import y no con require..
Si no te está funcionando bién el useState podría estar dandote problemas la creación de la variable que inicialmente declarás como array, y al no generar ese array al hacerle map te diría que no es una función..
tendrías que reemplazar esa línea por import {useState, useEffect} from "react"

Comment: Una vez asegurada de que funciona tu estado y que se crea el array este debería ser iterable, por lo que el siguiente problema presente podría ser que en alguna parte del código estés usando el setComoSistemas y estés modificando ese estado, si este estado queda con un valor que no sea un array, como undefined, null, etc al intentar hacer el map te arrojará el error que estás obteniendo.
Por último tal cual indica @g.4 los hooks se declaran arriba..

Comment: Corregí el import del useState y useEffect, además del orden de los hooks y aún continua el error de comboSistemas.map is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Aquí:

```
console.log('Chavos, sí está llamando combo sistemas', dataResponse);
```

Enseguida agrega otro console con lo siguiente:

```
console.log('Chavos, sí está llamando combo sistemas', dataResponse);
console.log(Array.isArray(dataResponse));
```

Si el resultado que muestra la consola es `false` quiere decir que `dataResponse` no es un valor tipo `array`, aún así se usa como valor en el `set` de:

```
succesFunc(dataResponse);
```

Donde `succesFunc` representa al estado `comboSistemas`, cuyo valor aunque no es un `array` (tipo iterable) se intenta iterar usando `map`:

```
comboSistemas.map((item) => 
            ...
);
```

Por lo que se JS manda el aviso de typeError:

> Uncaught TypeError: comboSistemas.map is not a function

Entonces puede que `dataResponse` sea una estructura tipo `dictionary/ JS object` donde alguna de sus propiedades puede tener asignado el `array` que se necesita.

Sugiero revisar el console de `dataResponse` y buscar una propiedad que tenga el `array` que se necesita, una vez que se identifique dicho `array` hay que cambiar el valor del `set`:

```
succesFunc(dataResponse.myArrayProp);
```

Con esto el *typeError* no se va a disparar pues ahora se esta usando el método `map` con un **tipo de dato iterable**

[isArray JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)